# Angular 6- Best way to pass data from template to controller?

Tags: angular

I've prepared a stackblitz with demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zhugxu

In above since we already have access to data in controller from where we're binding to template in the first place, is it optimal to pass the entire hero object from there, or is it better to just pass the id or even index using `i=index` in *ngFor, and getting our data from controller itself.

Granted for a small app like this, it doesn't matter, but what about larger apps with objects with several fields and sub fields?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I'm voting to close this question as opinion-based. Unless you give more details, it's still a choice of the developper, and any "best" judgement would depend on exact specifications. As a side comment/answer, for this kind of general questions, I'd just answer to any programmer "unless you have more specific needs, keep it readable, maintainable and understandable for your colleagues, you and your other you in 2 months"

Comment: Pass the object. That leads to the most clear and easy to understand code. Don't assume it's in any way inefficient, based on some vague feeling. It's not as if the object is copied or whatever. In fact, passing the id and then searching the object in a list is most likely much more inefficient than just passing the object. Don't write obscure, hard to read code because you believe (without knowing) that it's somehow more "optimal".

Comment: Thanks for the replies, the more you learn...

Answer (score 0):

Pass the object. Keeps the code readable I see no negative effects on performance.